# pass url from view to controller on PaypalReturnView

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, view, paypal, controller

I have almost got my mobile web app sorted, I just need to get the return url from the return page after finishing my paypal transaction, I need the url as it has the token and payerid so I can finish off the payment.

I have seen that I can get the Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, but is there anyway I can decode this so it is in a normal string format, that I can then extract the token and payerid, also is how do I get this information on the view loading, opposed to doing it on a button press..

Thanks

Comment: found it !!! Request.QueryString :-)